# Not able to login to my system?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am not able to login to my mac machine.
As soon as i login with correct  it brings me back to login screen.

If i put invalid password it gives password error.

Even i tried yo reinstall by going into safe mode but problem persists
.

Comment: You can’t reinstall in Safe Mode, only in Recovery.  Hold `Cmd-R` while booting.  Then try to reinstall

Comment: @allan thats what i did.

Comment: You shouldn’t have a password in Recovery.  How about Internet Recovery `Cmd-Opt-R`?  What Mac model do you have?

Comment: Mac book pro 2015. I have Catalina beta version installed

Comment: Try Internet recovery